# How to change get description (bloginfo) to get_cstegory

Tags: php, wordpress

I;m trying to change the code in this block below so that the description is the category - tried all sorts but nothing working - anyone have any ideas?

This is the line I assume I need to change...

$banner_sub_title = get_bloginfo( 'description' );

```
                    <?php if ( $display_header_text ) { ?>
                    <hgroup style="color: #<?php echo $header_textcolor; ?>">
                        <?php
                            $random_banner = get_posts(array(
                                'post_type' => 'post',
                                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                                'orderby' => 'rand',
                                'meta_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'use_as_banner',
                                        'value' => true,
                                    )
                                )
                            ));
                            if(!sizeof($random_banner)) {
                                $banner_link = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
                                $banner_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
                                $banner_sub_title = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
                            } else {
                                $banner_link = get_the_permalink($random_banner[0]);
                                $banner_title = get_the_title($random_banner[0]);
                                $banner_sub_title = get_the_excerpt($random_banner[0]);
                                if($banner_sub_title == '') {
                                    $banner_sub_title = wp_trim_words( get_post_field('post_content', $random_banner[0]), 10, null );
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo $banner_link; ?>"><?php echo $banner_title; ?></a></h1>
                        <h2 class="site-description"><a href="<?php echo $banner_link; ?>"><?php echo $banner_sub_title; ?></a></h2>
                    </hgroup>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
```